# simple 2 screen widget/app for android

Tags: android

I am unaware with android programming. Still need to develop an application similar to attached layout.

Please suggest some tutorial or open source android app maker or sample framework which can help me out to develop such applications without learning android programming.

Second page can be an image or text or HTML contents having scroll bar for large contents. I think putting flipping effect between pages of same chapter would be more complex than putting a scroll bar.

[image]

Comment: you probably can consider a web site

Answer (score 0):

You can try if the [App Inventor](http://www.appinventorbeta.com/about/) fits your needs - otherwise it's unlikely that you will be able to do it without gaining knowledge in android programming

Comment: BTW thought this should be mentioned. Google is retiring App Inventor. http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_retires_android_app_inventor_open-sources_t.php

Comment: :( I am aware with app inventor. Do you have some free software in your mind like "Android Magazine App Maker".